# C++ question: User think a number 1-100, program asks questions no more than 6 times to get answer. can't get correct

Tags: c++

User has to think of a number from 1 - 100. Computer keeps asking not more than 6 times to get what
the user think number. I could not get the logic right, I don't know how to fix anymore. Please somebody help me.

```
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
// this program is not correct
// try 24 you will see it
int main()
{
    cout << "Think of a number between 1 to 100\n";
    int max{100};
    int min{0};
    int answer{0};
    string response{"??"};

    while ((max - min) != 1)
    {
        cout << "Is the number < " << (max + min) / 2 << "?\n";
        cin >> response;
        if (response == "y" || response == "yes")
        {
            max = ((max + min) / 2);
            if ((max - min) == 1)
                answer = min;
        }
        else if (response == "n" || response == "no")
        {
            min = (max + min) / 2;
            if ((max - min) == 1)
                answer = max;
        }
        else
        {
            error("Invalid response\n");
        }
    }
    cout << "The answer is " << answer << endl;
    keep_window_open();
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Didn't exactly think about it much, but here's a hint: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/55444ccafd6cd32b

Comment: What is `#include "std_lib_facilities.h"` and where do I get it?

Comment: So if the computer is to act "human", then the computer should be picking a *random* number that is within the range of low and mid, or mid and high.  That's why your code is confusing (to me).

Comment: @ThomasSablik see my live demo instead?

Comment: @sehe Thanks but you try with the number 100, could get to the answer.

Comment: @WebforBeginner I know right. Like I said. I didn't exactly think long or hard. Here's another hint: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7a191fc0d0f4b3e

Comment: @ThomasSablik the #include .... is nothing same as <iostream> and error("") func only

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The computer is doing a binary search. The user picks a number.

Comment: @sehe u just sent me the same code u sent earlier.

Comment: @WebforBeginner no kidding? Did you look at the output section? That's how you debug this. Find the failing cases and trace them (with a debugger?)

Comment: The best way to find the problem is to start the program in a debugger and step through the code. Currently you are asking others for 40 minutes to debug your code. Using your debugger you would have found the problem after 5 minutes

Comment: @AdrianMole it's the same as ``answer == min`` already tried but failed randomly correct.

Comment: @sehe man, I debugged so many times could not figure out the correct logic. too difficult for me for now

Comment: others have different solutions but i just thought my code can be correct too. just could not figure out.

Comment: A debugger is a "different" solution??? No, it's the only solution for this problem if you can use one.

Comment: Please see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Now is a good time to learn how to debug your own programs.

Comment: @ThomasSablik no. not debugger. I mean other websites have different codes to solve this program. I just could not understand the debugger yet.

Comment: @ThomasSablik nearly got it, try 24, and you will see the answer is 25.

Comment: I think there is still some work to do. The program asks me 7 questions. It asks me if my number is `< 1`. Why do you set `min` to 0 is the user has to choose a number between 1 and 100?

Comment: Tried with ``min {1}`` too. I agree i should be using 1 instead. But the logic is still flawed.

Comment: The next problem is. If the program asks you if the number is `< 50` and your answer is "yes" the program should set `max` to 49. It can't be 50 anymore. When the program comes into a situation with `max - min == 1` it should ask for one of the numbers and set the `answer` corresponding to user's answer.

Comment: Let me try with that. Will let u know results.

Comment: The thing is my program still dont know the answer when the situation is like " its < 25 but > 23 " the obvious is 24 right?

Comment: @WebforBeginner: In your previous comment, is `25` supposed to be the value of `max` and is `23` supposed to be the value of `min`? If that is the case, then why are you writing `<25` instead of `<=25` and `>23` instead of `>=23`? There is a big difference between `<` and `<=`.

Comment: You should rethink the questions. The user has to choose a number between 1 and 100. The program asks if the number is smaller than 50. This will split the range into 1-49 and 50-100. The first range has 49 numbers and the second range has 51 numbers. The program should ask if the number is smaller than 51.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I hope your solution is right but how do i implement it in the code. not just on the string ` <=25 `

Comment: Let's do this step by step: First of all, you should ensure that `min` always contains the minimum possible value and that `max` always contains the maximum possible value. This means that you should initialize the value `min` to `1` instead of `0`, since you stated in your question that the user should guess a number between 1 and 100 instead of 0 to 100.

Comment: Next, for debugging purposes, I suggest you add the following line as the last line of your `while` loop: `cout << "min: " << min << " max: " << max << endl;`. That way, you will always see what the current value of `min` and `max` is when you run your program. Are these values always correct, for example, if you answer "yes" to the question if the number is < 50?

Comment: Although I am not one of the people who downvoted your question, I think you should read the following link for an explanation why you got so many downvotes: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) Also, someone else posted a [link](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) on how to debug your own programs, which you should also read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has already been pointed out in the comments section, there are at least 3 bugs in your code:

1. Your question states that the user should think of a number between 1 and 100, but the variables `min` and `max` are initialized to 0 and 100, as if the user was supposed to think of a number between 0 and 100. Therefore, you should initialize `min` to `1` instead of `0`.
2. When the user replies "yes" to the question whether the number is below a certain value, you set `max` to this value. This does not make sense, because you know that the number cannot be this value, but must be below this value. Therefore, you should set `max` to this value minus 1.
3. When `min == 1` and `max == 2`, it would make sense for the next question your program asks to be whether the number is "< 2", in order to determine whether the number is `1` or `2`. However, in that case, your program asks whether the number is "< 1", which does not make sense, because it already knows that the answer to that question is "no". Therefore, instead of asking whether the number is smaller than `(max + min) / 2`, it would make more sense to ask whether the number is smaller than `(max + min + 1) / 2`.

I have cleaned up your code a bit and fixed the bugs mentioned above. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

constexpr int MIN = 1;
constexpr int MAX = 100;

int main()
{
    int min{ MIN };
    int max{ MAX };
    std::string response;

    std::cout << "Think of a number between " << MIN << " and " << MAX << "." << std::endl;

    while ( min != max )
    {
        int guess = (max + min + 1) / 2;
        std::cout << "Is the number < " << guess << "? ";
        std::cin >> response;
        if ( response == "y" || response == "yes" )
        {
            max = guess - 1;
        }
        else if ( response == "n" || response == "no" )
        {
            min = guess;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid response" << std::endl;
        }

        //The following line only exists for debugging purposes and can be disabled
        std::cout << "min: " << min << " max: " << max << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "The number is " << min << "." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I have rearranged the code in such a way that the numbers `1` and `100` are hard-coded only in one place, instead of several places in the program. This allows you to change the range very easily, without having to change the numbers in several places in the program.

One thing that my code does not do is stop asking after 6 questions, because it can take up to 7 questions to find the correct answer. In your question, you specified that it should ask not more than 6 times, but did not specify what should happen if it has not found the answer by then.

Comment: Thank you so much. You help me so much. Like Bjarne Stroustrup says, this kind of thing is hard work, i can't get it alone. You help me a lot. God bless you.